# SQL IBM DB2 (Windows 10) not reading end if; (stored procedure)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I'm getting this error for my stored procedure. My ibm db2 doesn't seem to be reading the `END IF;` statement.

I'm using Windows 10 for my db2.

Error message:

> SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END@" was found following "_Details)".  Expected
>   tokens may include:  "END IF".

My code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SeatPricing (IN seat_num varchar(2), ticket_id varchar(10))
BEGIN 
    IF seat_num LIKE 'A_' THEN
    UPDATE Ticket_Details 
    SET seat_price = 500.00
    WHERE ticket_id = (SELECT ticket_id
                       FROM Ticket_Details);
    UPDATE Ticket 
    SET seat_price = 500.00
    WHERE ticket_id = (SELECT ticket_id
                       FROM Ticket);
  ELSE 
    UPDATE Ticket_Details
    SET seat_price = 300.00
    WHERE ticket_id = (SELECT ticket_id
                       FROM Ticket_Details);
    UPDATE Ticket
    SET seat_price = 300.00
    WHERE ticket_id = (SELECT ticket_id
                       FROM Ticket);
    END IF;
 END@
 /
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple problem into your stored procedure:

1. @ to the end
2. You dont use ticket_id into your updates
3. You update all your tables, your where are not necessary. When you do it: "where id = id (when you do ticket_id = (SELECT ticket_id FROM Ticket)" your take all ticket id I think.
4. Your if do the same query but change only one parameter, you should be simply this.
5. It's an error to have price column into your Ticket_Details table and ticket table, but it's may be a choice... The price can may be change into ticket table  and not Ticket_Details table in same time (its a context question).

I propose this code :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SeatPricing (IN seat_num varchar(2),IN ticketid varchar(10))
BEGIN 
DECLARE VALUETOSET decimal(5, 2);

IF seat_num LIKE 'A_' THEN
    SET VALUETOSET= 500.00 ;
ELSE
    SET VALUETOSET= 300.00 ;
END IF ;

UPDATE Ticket_Details SET seat_price = VALUETOSET and ticket_id = ticketid;

UPDATE Ticket SET seat_price = VALUETOSET and ticket_id = ticketid;

END
```

Comment: Thank you so muchhhh!! No. 3 was very helpful, and so does the others. :))))))

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR MESSAGE: SQL0104N An unexpected token "END@" was found following
>   "_Details)". Expected tokens may include: " END IF".

Always refer the syntax for **[creating procedure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008328.html)**. You need to end your procedure by ***ONLY*** `END` with optional `<procedure-name>`.

But, you have used `END@` at the end, which should be either `END` or `END SeatPricing`.

> END - A mandatory keyword that ends the block. **You can optionally
>   specify the name of the procedure**.